# Exploitation: EIP refuse to jump to the stack although it's executable

Tags: linux, exploit, buffer-overflow, c, reverse-engineering

I wrote a [program](http://pastebin.com/0HBsVWRt) in C that is exploitable to BOF.

> **TL;DR** - My payload (NOP-sled + shellcode + return address) overrides EIP but I can't set EIP to point to the
>   address of my payload, although I can set EIP to
>   be anywhere else outside the Stack adress-range. Stack seems to be
>   executable and the proections I familiar with are off.

I sent a payload using `ragg2` De bruijin pattern, and found the offset that overrides EIP. I then created a payload with NOP-sled, then shellcode, and at the offset that overrides EIP I wrote the address of the middle of my NOP-sled.

So the payload looked something like this: `NOP-sled + Shellcode + Address somewhere at the middle of my NOP-Sled (Little Endian).`

Something strange happened and I wasn't able to exploit the program: after the segfault, EIP wasn't at the address I used at the end of my payload, EIP was like 600 addresses after. But when I changed the address at the end of my payload to something else, like "AABB" (0x42424141), or 0xd4d4**fd**ff (instead of 0xd4d4**ff**ff that is an address at the middle of my shellcode, little-endian) it worked just fine and EIP was at the address I supplied.

`nx` protection is off, `ASLR` is disabled, `Selinux` disabled, the memory page seems to be executable and the ELF compiled using `"-fno-stack-protector -z execstack"` on GCC.

Tried it also on gdb and also outside of any debugger.

what can be the problem? Why it refuses to jump to the address on the stack?

**Info about the binary:**

```
havecode true
pic      false
canary   false
nx       false
crypto   false
va       true
intrp    /lib/ld-linux.so.2
bintype  elf
class    ELF32
lang     c
arch     x86
bits     32
machine  Intel 80386
os       linux
minopsz  1
maxopsz  16
pcalign  0
subsys   linux
endian   little
stripped false
static   false
linenum  true
lsyms    true
relocs   true
rpath    NONE
binsz    6162
```

**Info about the stack:**

```
sys 132K 0xfffdd000 - 0xffffe000 s -rwx [stack] [stack] ; map._stack_._rwx
```

**EDIT:**
You can find more details, including commands and the shellcode itself here:
http://pastebin.com/HYbByNSE

Comment: Can you post your shellcode and the full command line arguments/env/exploit you're using to execute this?

Comment: Here you go, tell me if you need anymore data: http://pastebin.com/HYbByNSE

Comment: Is it possible that 0xd4d4ffff isn't actually in the NOP sled? Did you get that address in gdb by any chance?

Comment: I got it in radare2. The payload isn't working in r2 debug mode even though it supposed to work. I know that the addresses are changed inside a debugger like r2 or gdb so I also tried the payload with different addresses +-20 bytes. The thing is that EIP isn't taking any address from the range of the stack, any other address works fine. So 0xd4d4ffff is on the NOP-Sled when I try to exploit the program in radare2 but of course it might not be on the stack outside r2, that;s why I tried another addresses.

Comment: Without looking at it too much, I got it working just by reducing the NOP's to 24. Similar environment (32 bit, NX and ASLR disabled)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the payload that you posted, It seems that you want EIP to jump to 0xffffd4d4. Set a breakpoint at that address (0xffffd4d4) before running the program. This way you will know if program execution ever reached 0xffffd4d4.

Maybe there is a problem in the Shellcode and your program might be segfaulting halfway through the shellcode. I had a lot of similar problems when I had started out.

PS. In your question you mentioned 0xd4d4ffff. Please check. Because if you want to jump to 0xd4d4ffff you need to replace EIP with \xff\xff\xd4\xd4 and not \xd4\xd4\xff\xff.